# lazy-seq for recursive function

Tags: recursion, clojure, sequence, lazy-evaluation

Sorry for the vague title, I guess I just don't understand my problem well enough to ask it yet but here goes. I want to write a recursive function which takes a sequence of functions to evaluate and then calls itself with their results & so on. The recursion stops at some function which returns a number.

However, I would like the function being evaluated at any point in the recursion, f, to be wrapped in a function, s, which returns an initial value (say 0, or the result of another function i) the first time it is evaluated,  followed by the result of evaluating f (so that the next time it is evaluated it returns the previously evaluated result, and computes the next value). The aim is to decouple the recursion so that it can proceed without causing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349063/lazy-seq-for-recursive-function).

I think I'm asking for a lazy-seq. It's a pipe that's filling-up with evaluations of a function at one end, and historical results are coming out of the other.

Answer (score 3):

Your description reminds me some of [reductions](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reductions)? Reductions will perform a reduce and return all the intermediate results.

```
user> (reductions + (range 10))
(0 1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45)
```

Here (range 10) creates a seq of 0 to 9.  Reductions applies + repeatedly, passing the previous result of + and the next item in the sequence.  All of the intermediate results are returned.  You might find it instructive to look at the [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/b578c69d7480f621841ebcafdfa98e33fcb765f6/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5576) of reductions.

If you need to build a test (check for value) into this, that's easy to do with an if in your function (although it won't stop traversing the seq).  If you want early exit on a condition being true, then you'll need to write your own loop/recur which amalloy has already done well.

I hate to say it, but I suspect this might also be a case for the State Monad but IANAMG (I Am Not A Monad Guy).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your entire goal: a lot of the terms you use are vague. Like, what do you mean you want to evaluate a sequence of functions and then recur on their results? These functions must be no-arg functions (thunks), then, I suppose? But having a thunk which first returns x, and then returns y the next time you call it, is pretty vile and stateful. Perhaps [trampoline](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/trampoline) will solve part of your problem?

You also linked to something you want to avoid, but seem to have pasted the wrong link - it's just a link back to this page. If what you want to avoid is stack overflow, then trampoline is likely to be an okay way to go about it, although it should be possible with just loop/recur. This notion of thunks returning x unless they return y is *madness*, if avoiding stack overflow is your primary goal. Do not do that.

I've gone ahead and taken a guess at the most plausible end goal you might have, and here's my implementation:

```
(defn call-until-number [& fs]
  (let [numeric (fn [x] (when (number? x) x))]
    (loop [fs fs]
      (let [result (map #(%) fs)]
        (or (some numeric result)
            (recur result))))))

(call-until-number (fn [] (fn [] 1))) ; yields 1
(call-until-number (fn [] (fn [] 1))  ; yields 2
                   (fn [] 2))
(call-until-number (fn f [] f)) ; never returns, no overflow
```